# Docker disconnect all containers from docker network

Tags: bash, docker, docker-network

I have docker network "my_network". I  want to remove this docker network with `docker network rm my_network`. Before it I should disconnect all my containers from this network. I can use `docker network inspect` and get output like

```
[
    {
        "Name": "my_network",
        "Id": "aaaaaa",
        "Scope": "some_value",
        "Driver": "another_value",
        "EnableIPv6": bool_value,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.0.0/1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "bbb": {
                "Name": "my_container_1",
                "EndpointID": "ENDPOITID1",
                "MacAddress": "MacAddress1",
                "IPv4Address": "0.0.0.0/1",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ccc": {
                "Name": "my_container_2",
                "EndpointID": "ENDPOINTID2",
                "MacAddress": "MacAddress2",
                "IPv4Address": "0.0.0.0/2",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

It is okay to manual disconnect if  I have only several containers but if I have 50 containers I have problem.
How can I disconnect all containers from this network with single or several command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`docker network inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_inspect/) has a [format option](http://docs.master.dockerproject.org/engine/admin/formatting/).

That means you can list all Container names with:

```
docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{.Name}}{{end}}' network_name
```

That should then be easy, by script, to read each name and call [`docker network disconnect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_disconnect/).

[wwerner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193637/wwerner) proposes below [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194602/docker-disconnect-all-containers-from-docker-network/41194696#comment74789454_41194696) the following command:

```
for i in ` docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{.Name}} {{end}}' network_name`; do docker network disconnect -f network_name $i; done;
```

In multiple line for readability:

```
for i in ` docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{.Name}} {{end}}' network_name`;\
  do \
     docker network disconnect -f network_name $i; \
  done;
```

Adding:

> Note that there is a space in the format as opposed to the answer to split the names by a space.

Comment: Can you please fix from `docker inspect` to `docker network inspect`.
It does work! Thank you so much.

Comment: To add a copy'n'pasteable solution: ``for i in ` docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{.Name}} {{end}}' network_name`; do  docker network disconnect -f network_name $i; done;``. Note that there is a space in the format as opposed to the answer to split the names by a space.

Comment: @wwerner Thank you. I have included your command in the answer for more visibility.